# AWS ECS Tasks - when in the state machine do charges begin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I use AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS) `run-task` to schedule tasks using both EC2 and Fargate, and I use `stop-task` to cancel some of them.

The state machine seems to be `PROVISIONING` -> `PENDING` -> `ACTIVE`. I know for sure that if I `stop-task` during `ACTIVE` I am charged at least a 1-minute minimum. I am guessing that if I `stop-task` during `PROVISIONING` I am not charged the 1-minute minimum. I am not sure about `PENDING`.

I am not sure about this and have been unable to find any documentation on the AWS site. Does anyone know? Can anyone point me to documentation that shows the answer one way or the other?

Comment: Based on the Fargate Pricing documentation, it says pricing is calculated from the time you start to download your container image until the Amazon ECS Task terminates.

Comment: @Haran I assume you mean https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/. Do you know which state they mean when they say "Duration is calculated from the time you start to download your container image (docker pull) until the Task terminates"? Is that Provisioning, Pending, or some other state?